# How to make tool font size bigger in Construct2 IDE

Tags: windows-10, construct-2

I'm using c2 with windows 10. Surface3 with a side monitor that has a resolution of 2160x1440.  The text on the IDE for C2 is tiny.  Any way to increase the font size used in the IDE similar to what you can do with Visual Studio or Android Studio?

Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 1):

To change the font size you have a couple of options.  First off, you can go into File->Preferences and then under General, they have a section for Event Sheet View.  There you can change the font size in the event sheet.  Additionally, you can simply do a Control+Scroll (up or down) to zoom in there as well.

Comment: Any way to get the menus bigger?